# Why is the rarest output always displayed? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I run this function, the output is

```
You found emerald!
```

Why?
With a tiny 3/999 chance of finding emerald, I should usually find something else. It cannot be pure chance. I have reviewed the code and I can't find the issue.

```
block=randint(1,1000)
    if block==456 or 742 or 327:
        print('You found emerald!')
    elif block==275 or 467 or 234 or 978 or 10 or 3 or 256 or 475 or 103 or 701 or 124 or 9:
        print('You found diamond!')
    elif block==range(900,930):
        print('You found iron!')
    elif block==range(800,870):
        print('You found coal!')
    else:
        print('You found stone...')
```

Comment: the test should be `if block in (456, 742, 327):`

Comment: So when do I use `==` and when do I use `in`?

Comment: `==` will work for one value, use `in` to check multiple. btw, `block==range(900,930)` cannot work (use `block in range(900,930)` instead)

Answer (score 2):

While your condition might make sense in English, it doesn't actually do what you expect it to do in python. Let's break it down.

```
if block==456 or 742 or 327:
```

What you have here is a boolean statement with a true/false value, that's composed of three sub-statements:

```
if (block==456) or (742) or (327):
```

That's because the way python syntax works, `==` is a binary operator (meaning it has two operands, one on the left, one on the right) and `or` is, likewise, a binary operator. So the python interpreter doesn't parse it as:

```
if block == (456 or 742 or 327):
```

merely because, well, that's not how python was designed to work.

So why does `emerald` get picked every time? because in this statement:

```
if (block==456) or (742) or (327):
```

you're checking the true/false value of the number "742". As per python's rules (and many other languages as well), the value "0" will be evaluated as `false`, but any other number will count as `true`. So your test resolves to:

```
if (block==456) or (True) or (True):
```

And that means it will *always* return True, which is why it will *always* enter the first conditional branch, and return the rarest result.

As others have mentioned in the comments, what you want isn't an *equality* check, but a check that the value is contained in a list:

```
if block in (456, 742, 327):
```

This will check if the value of `block` is inside the list of values specified.

Comment: Well, I STILL get an error if I try that.

Answer (score 1):

Why because your conditionals boil down to

`if (block==456) or (742) or (327):`

Anything other than a `0` is evaluated to `True`. In this case, `742` evaluated to `True` and hence `print('You found emerald!')` gets executed.

Change your tests to either

`if (block==456) or (block==742) or (block==327)`
or
`if block in (456,742,327)`